# extbase: map sys_category to model

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

I try to use in an extbase extension sys_category and run into this error:

Table 'mydb.tx_extension_domain_model_category' doesn't exist

That ist correct, there is no table with this name: i want to use sys_category. It seems that the mapping does not work - i tried this:

```
plugin.tx_extension_pi1 {
    persistence {
        classes {
            \Lisardo\Extension\Domain\Model\Category {
                mapping {
                    tableName = sys_category
                    recordType = \Lisardo\Extension\Domain\Model\Category
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I worked along this example: https://gist.github.com/iamandrewluca/7b9a7a3d5463f6f27f668eb2fcdda1ad - i presume that it is too old.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without testing I would propose the following TypoScript:

```
config.tx_extbase {
    persistence {
        classes {
            Lisardo\Extension\Domain\Model\Category {
                mapping {
                    tableName = sys_category
                    recordType = \Lisardo\Extension\Domain\Model\Category
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you don't need the Single Table Inheritance, I would propose to skip the line with `recordType`.

---

A working example can be found in the news extension, see https://github.com/georgringer/news/blob/master/ext_typoscript_setup.txt.